# lru_cache for dual recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, memoization

I understand the implementation of **dfs** without memoization tend to time out quickly since we are recomputing the same thing over and over again. This is a perfect need for `lru_cache` in python. For example:

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache
def fib(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
```

However, I am struggling with implementing memoization with `lru_cache` for dual recursion with a slight difference. Soon as I add the decorate `lru_cache` to the code (whose the meaning is explained in the figure below, [Leetcode494](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/)), it gives a wrong result. The reason is simple becasue `helper( cumsum+nums[i], i+1)` and `helper( cumsum-nums[i], i+1)` do different things.

```
from functools import lru_cache
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        # tree structure: two path "+" or "-"

        # @lru_cache
        def helper(cumsum, i):
            nonlocal n 
            if i == len(nums) and cumsum == target:
                n += 1 
                return n 
            if i == len(nums):
                return 
            
            helper( cumsum+nums[i], i+1)
            helper( cumsum-nums[i], i+1)
        
        nums = tuple(nums)
        n = 0
        cumsum = 0
        helper(cumsum, 0)
        return n
```

In this situation, is it still possible to use `lru_cache` to memoize the the intermediate results? If so, could you please share your wisdom? Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: You could also consider DP approach on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this approach and compare the difference.

```
from functools import lru_cache
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, a: List[int], S: int) -> int:
        
        N = len(a)
        
        @lru_cache(None)
        def helper(i,S):
            if i == N:
                if S == 0:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return 0
            return helper(i+1,S + a[i]) + helper(i+1,S - a[i])
        
        return helper(0,S)
```